# "ImportError: Couldn't import Django." even after installing Django within Virtualenv

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I'm a newbie in Python, and I'm just getting into Django tutorials. I get the concept of creating a virtual environment, installing Django in it and then setting up my project structure alongside it. But then, I must have messed something up, because my "python manage.py migrate" command returns an error that it can't find a module named Django, despite the fact that I had just installed Django. Here's what I did:

```
PS D:\f drive\KK\Projects\Git\python\Dev> virtualenv kk_env
Using base prefix 'c:\\program files\\python37'
New python executable in D:\f drive\KK\Projects\Git\python\Dev\kk_env\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
PS D:\f drive\KK\Projects\Git\python\Dev> pipenv --python 3.7 install django==2.2
Virtualenv already exists!
Removing existing virtualenv…
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: D:\f drive\KK\Projects\Git\python\Dev\Pipfile
Using C:/Python/Python37-32/python.exe (3.7.4) to create virtualenv…
[=   ] Creating virtual environment...Already using interpreter C:\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Using base prefix 'C:\\Python\\Python37-32'
New python executable in C:\Users\karthik\.virtualenvs\Dev-g5SlP1CQ\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
Running virtualenv with interpreter C:/Python/Python37-32/python.exe

Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: C:\Users\karthik\.virtualenvs\Dev-g5SlP1CQ
Creating a Pipfile for this project…
Installing django==2.2…
Adding django to Pipfile's [packages]…
Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Success!
Updated Pipfile.lock (f002eb)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (f002eb)…
  ================================ 3/3 - 00:00:01
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
PS D:\f drive\KK\Projects\Git\python\Dev> pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS D:\f drive\KK\Projects\Git\python\Dev> deactivate
PS D:\f drive\KK\Projects\Git\python\Dev> kk_env/Scripts/activate
(kk_env) PS D:\f drive\KK\Projects\Git\python\Dev> django-admin startproject dj_site
(kk_env) PS D:\f drive\KK\Projects\Git\python\Dev> mv dj_site dj_root
(kk_env) PS D:\f drive\KK\Projects\Git\python\Dev> cd dj_root
(kk_env) PS D:\f drive\KK\Projects\Git\python\Dev\dj_root> ls


    Directory: D:\f drive\KK\Projects\Git\python\Dev\dj_root


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        9/27/2019  12:12 AM                dj_site
-a----        9/27/2019  12:12 AM            648 manage.py


(kk_env) PS D:\f drive\KK\Projects\Git\python\Dev\dj_root> python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

As might be obvious from my PowerShell's history, I'm following conventions from two different tutorials, and I suspect that it has something to do with this screw-up (my best guess is using "pipenv" vs "pip" for installing Django. But that forms my second question).

I've got two questions now:

1. How do I tap out of this situation? (I'm attaching a screenshot of my project structure as well, if it is of any help)
2. In my previous attempt (following n attempts), I had followed almost these same steps except for using 'pip install "django>=2.2,<3"' to install Django. Everything worked fine except that I saw NO 'pipfile' or 'pipfile.lock' created as part of that installation. My vague understanding is that pipfile is needed for my project's portability, and I really wanted to get it right while doing the basics. Is this (missing of pipfile) to be expected or am I better off doing gardening?

[VS Code project screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM95j.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It kind of seems like you're in the wrong virtual environment, and you left the one pipenv created and went into another, which doesn't have Django installed.

You're probably right that it's to do with following two processes. Instead you will probably find it easier to only use pipenv.

To tap out, just remove your directory and start a new powershell window.

Then, all you should really need, assuming you already have pipenv installed - which it seems like you do - is this:

```
pipenv install django
pipenv shell
django-admin startproject dj_site
cd dj_site
python manage.py migrate
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I suspected as much, but it really helps knowing the intricacies involved. Appreciate your guidance. Would you have any idea about my second question as well?

Comment: Sure, since you didn't use pipenv the second time, there's no Pipfile, as this is specific to pipenv.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks, Tom. That solves both of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your first command -
`PS D:\f drive\KK\Projects\Git\python\Dev> virtualenv kk_env`  is creating a virtual environment in your `pwd`.

Your second command - `PS D:\f drive\KK\Projects\Git\python\Dev> pipenv --python 3.7 install django==2.2` is creating a virtual environment at `C:\Users\karthik\.virtualenvs\Dev-g5SlP1CQ` as evident from the output statements -

```
Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: C:\Users\karthik\.virtualenvs\Dev-g5SlP1CQ
```

Now, you are installing Django in the above virtual environment and not in `kk_env`. This may be the reason for you getting the error you described in the question.

You can run the following commands in the sequence they appear to achieve what you want!

1. `virtualenv kk_venv`
2. `kk_env/Scripts/activate`
3. `pip install django`

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Now I could see where it went wrong. Any idea why pipenv would create the virtual environment within my user directory as opposed to the current working directory?